# What line of code could I use in C++ to disable energy saver?

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to prevent the monitor from going to sleep (the windows setting, not the monitor setting). I am using c++. What call do I make?

Answer (score 13):

```
class KeepDisplayOn
{
public:
    KeepDisplayOn()
    {
        mPrevExecState = ::SetThreadExecutionState(ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED | ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | ES_CONTINUOUS);
        ::SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENSAVETIMEOUT, 0, &mPrevScreenSaver, 0);
        ::SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETSCREENSAVETIMEOUT, FALSE, NULL, 0);
    }

    ~KeepDisplayOn()
    {
        ::SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETSCREENSAVETIMEOUT, mPrevScreenSaver, NULL, 0);
        ::SetThreadExecutionState(mPrevExecState);
    }

private:
    UINT                mPrevScreenSaver;
    EXECUTION_STATE     mPrevExecState;
};
```

Comment: But setting the screen saver time out is not necessary once you set the thread execution state to ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED. What if the user wants to change the screen saver settings while the application's running?

Answer (score 5):

A simpler way that doesn't modify global system state like the first response does:

In your window procedure, add a handler for `WM_SYSCOMMAND`. When wParam is `SC_MONITORPOWER`, return 0 instead of deferring to `DefWindowProc`. (When wParam is any other value, make sure you either handle the message or pass it to `DefWindowProc`. Otherwise the user will have difficulty adjusting your window at runtime.)

Answer (score 3):

`SetThreadExecutionState(ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED|ES_CONTINUOUS);`

Answer (score 1):

Wiggle the mouse every minute or so.

```
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE,1,0,0,0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE,-1,0,0,0);
Sleep(60000);
```