# Use NativeWindow to disable screensaver

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to disable the screensaver and monitor power off. At this stage there's no windows form, which I could youse. Thus I wan't to use NativeWindow.

Here's my code

```
sealed class ObserverWindow : NativeWindow, IDisposable
{
    internal ObserverWindow()
    {
        this.CreateHandle(new CreateParams()
        {
            Parent= IntPtr.Zero
        });

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        DestroyHandle();
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message msg)
    {
        if (msg.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND &&
            ((((long)msg.WParam & 0xFFF0) == SC_SCREENSAVE) ||
            ((long)msg.WParam & 0xFFF0) == SC_MONITORPOWER))
        {
            msg.Msg = 0;
            msg.HWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref msg);
    }
}
```

The Problem is, that the WndProc is not called with WM_SYSCOMMAND. Actualy the WndProc is called 4 times. At the last call there's msg.Msg == WM_CREATE.

I think I'm missing some create parameter. Does anyone have advise?

Regards Michael

**UPDATE**

I was running the code in a non STA thread. Thus the window did not reveive any messages exept the initial ones. Now I'm receiving WM_SYSCOMMAND messages. But when the screensaver is activated, there's no message.

I also tried to overwrite a Form's WndProc with the same result. But this used to work in Windows XP. Is there a change in Windows 7?

OS: Windows 7 64bit.

**SOLUTION**

As a comment in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003394/what-line-of-code-could-i-use-in-c-to-disable-energy-saver) states, only the foreground window can cancel the screensaver. Thus the above code can't work. The NativeWindow is great for receiving messages, but not for canceling a screensaver. For latter I recommend the answer to this question.

Comment: FYI: Message number 1 is `WM_CREATE`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper way to do this is by telling Windows that your thread needs to have the display active.  Commonly used by video players.  P/Invoke the SetThreadExecutionState() API function, pass ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED.  And ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED to keep the machine from shutting down automatically.  Visit pinvoke.net for the required declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the screen saver is much easier, according to [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/140723):

> This can be done easily using:
>
> ```
> SystemParametersInfo( SPI_SETSCREENSAVEACTIVE,
>                       FALSE,
>                       0,
>                       SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE
>                     );
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> If you need the screen saver to start up again, you'll need to reinitialize the time-out period. Do this by [c]alling `SystemParametersInfo (SPI_SETSCREENSAVEACTIVE, TRUE, 0, SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE)`.

Comment: This would probably do it, but my intension is to disable the screensaver temporarely. Your approach would overwrite any change done by the user. Anyway I missed to mention, that I wan't to disable power saving also.

Answer (score 0):

You could try overriding [`DefWndProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.defwndproc.aspx) instead.

```
public override void DefWndProc(ref Message msg)
{
    if (msg.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND &&
        ((((long)msg.WParam & 0xFFF0) == SC_SCREENSAVE) ||
        ((long)msg.WParam & 0xFFF0) == SC_MONITORPOWER))
    {
        msg.Msg = 0;
        msg.HWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
    }
    base.DefWndProc(ref msg);
}
```

I'm not on a Windows box right now, so I cannot test this. Let me know if it works.